# Too many redirects on IIS 7.5's web.config (when redirecting all but a few pages)

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have a subdomain on a client's website that has too many addresses returning 404 (in which people access through old links) and some that exists but shouldn't show to the user.

So we decided to redirect everything to a main page, except for a few pages that we do want to leave there, without redirection.

The code looks like this:

```
<rule name="Redirect Everything" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">

        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/page/noredirect1$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/page/noredirect2$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/page/noredirect3$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/page/noredirect4$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/page/noredirect5$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/page/noredirect6$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/page/noredirect7$" ignoreCase="true" />

    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://subdomain.domain.com/page/noredirect5" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

However, that is creating a "Too many redirects" message! Any idea on how to halt the redirection loop? I've tried adding `<clear />` before the `<rule>` tag but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: I think you want "`MatchAll`", not "`MatchAny`" as you're using `negate="true"`.

Comment: Hmm, you are right, @Dai, but that alone didn't do the trick.

Comment: You also need to change your initial `<match />` condition - right now it's capturing every request.

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea. I wanted to match every page, except for the ones listed on the conditions.